# How to pass an object's method as a parameter to another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

First take a look at my simple codes below:

```
function mySecondFunction(objArray,setFunc)
{
    for (let i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++)
    {
        objArray[i].info.setTop(72);
    }
}

function myFunction()
{
    let myObjArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    myObjArray.push({
        info:{topVar:0,
          bottomVar:0,
          get top() {return this.topVar;},
          get bottom() {return this.bottomVar;},
          setTop: function(input) {this.topVar = input;},
          setBottom: function(input) {this.bottomVar = input; }
         }
    });
    }
    mySecondFunction(myObjArray); // This works Fine
    mySecondFunction(myObjArray,setTop); // I want something like this!!!
}
```

As you can see, I want to pass a method of an object to another function. I know a lot of possible solutions to avoid this, but I want to know whether it is possible or not.

Comment: I can think of several ways to do this. How do you want to be able to call the method? `objArray[i].info[setFunc](72)`? `setFunc.call(objArray[i].info, 72)`? `setFunc(objArray[i].info, 72)`?

Comment: @melpomene I got an answer for one of them. Can you give other possible solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Detach it and pass as an argument. Remember to use `call` to set the intended `this` value.

```js
function mySecondFunction(objArray, setFunc)
{
    for (let i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++)
    {
        setFunc.call(objArray[i].info, 72); 
        /* explicitly telling that: 
        please set 'this' value in this function to be 'objArray[i].info' when running, 
        allowing, e.g. `this.topVar` in 
        `setTop: function(input) {this.topVar = input;}` 
        to be operating on `objArray[i].info.topVar` */
    }
}

function myFunction()
{
    let myObjArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    myObjArray.push({
        info:{topVar:0,
          bottomVar:0,
          get top() {return this.topVar;},
          get bottom() {return this.bottomVar;},
          setTop: function(input) {this.topVar = input;},
          setBottom: function(input) {this.bottomVar = input; }
         }
    });
    }
    mySecondFunction(myObjArray, myObjArray[0].info.setTop); 
    /* once detaching the method from the object, 
    (if we are not using arrow functions), 
    we lose 'this' value, meaning we are losing 
    the target of object that we want to operate on */
    
    console.log(myObjArray)
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: That's a great solution. but can we somehow avoid passing 0 index?

Comment: @Reza you can declare a function independent of objects, for example just `var setTop = function(input) {this.topVar = input;}`, and use `setTop.call(thisValue)` to bind `thisValue` to `this` and make references to `this.topVar` work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can target item number in the array list. You can do statically (i.e. 1-???) or dynamically with an iteration and a variable. You can then the object property within that. For example:

```
myObjArray[0].info.setTop
```

That will target the 1st item in the array. Be sure to omit parentheses (`()`) when passing the method as you want to pass the function reference **not** the result

Comment: You mean "*…pass the function reference*" but you also need to deal with how to get *this* in the method to reference the correct object.

Comment: @RobG thank you for the correction. Ah yes I did not see the use of `this`. it is dependent on what OP wanted the scope of `this` to be

Comment: @wmash although your answer is correct but I don't want to pass the index statically. Anyway, thank you.